# TestCleanup cannot be async?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, mstest

As far as I understand testcleanup can't be async for example (for example here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3a23bd9d-7a5a-490e-a199-b8dfa309f39e/unittesting-problem-with-async-testinitialize-method?forum=vstest)

But i didn't found anything in official documentation(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcleanupattribute.aspx) also it does compiled in VS successfully.

I have two questions:

1. Could someone explain to me why?
2. Is there any official documentation about it?

Comment: Do you have code where the async cleanup is called and working/not working? It seems more a question for Microsoft to answer than SO. It is there API.

Comment: Looking at the thread, the second answer says in 2013 that it is now supported,  they only mention initialize, but cleanup is probably now supported as well.  If it isn't crashing and you are getting good results, you are probably fine.

Comment: I don't know exactly why this isn't working in the VS Test framework, but I was able to confirm that on my own that Visual Studio's framework and NUnit 2.x don't work with async calls, but I also found that NUnit 3.x solves that problem and does handle async just fine in its TearDown call.

Answer (score 0):

At least for Visual Studio 2019 and 2022 it can be used the `async` syntax to do this:

```
[TestCleanup]
public async Task TestCleanup()
{
}
```

See: [Microsoft Documentation 'Use the MSTest framework in unit tests'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/visualstudio/test/using-microsoft-visualstudio-testtools-unittesting-members-in-unit-tests?view=vs-2022#test)